# Binding a repeater in C# has duplicates

Tags: data-binding, repeater

I have a repeater control I am trying to group this but it is showing duplicates

Here is what it is doing:
[image]

**Repeater Control**

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="GroupRepeater" OnItemDataBound="GroupRepeater_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="CompanyName" runat="server" />
                   
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>     
                <div id="BoardGrpName">
                    <%# Eval("BoardGroupName") %>
                </div> 
                <div id="BoardCompanyName1">
                    <%# Eval("CompanyName") %>
                </div>
                <div id="BoardCompanyName2">
                    <%# Eval("BoardMemberName") %>
                </div>
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <div class="label label-light" id="BoardMemberName">                                       
                    <asp:Label ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="12px" runat="server"><%# Eval("BoardMemberName") %></asp:Label>                                                                                       
                </div>               
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

**Code Behind**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    //load board members                    
                    GroupRepeater.DataSource = DbHelper.SqlStoredProcedureDataTable("spQueryFullBoardInfo", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                    GroupRepeater.DataBind();
                    divMessage.Visible = false;                   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               catch error here
            }           
        }
```

[image: DB from SP]

I have tried many things.  Moving it to the header, binding to a list but I get the same results.  I am guessing it is something simple i am missing.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?  Please?

Comment: :( :( :( :( :( :(

Comment: Nevermind. Not sure why I can't get any help on this.. have a great day everyone.